# Why doesn't my mercurial pre-commit hook work in MinGW

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mingw, mercurial-hook

I have a pre-commit hook in my .hgrc file which checks if more than 5MB of files will be added to the repository. The hook is:

```
pre-commit.added-files-too-large = test 5000 -gt `hg status --added --no-status --print0 | xargs --null ls -lk | awk \'{sum += $5} END {print sum}\'`
```

This works fine on Linux (using bash) but doesn't work on MinGW. If I simply run the same command from the MinGW shell command line it works as expected.

The error message is

```
test: invalid integer ``hg'
```

I suspect that the error is something to do with how things are quoted but I've tried lots of combinations (including changing the backticks to $()) and I can't seem to find the correct answer.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the embedded script prints an error of some kind so test sees a string instead of a number.

Run the command `hs status...` from the command line to see what it prints.

Comment: Running the `hg status ...` command on its own produces a number which is the size of the added files as expected. Thanks are still due though, you have helped me realise that there is an issue if there are no added files (in this case it prints the size of the files in the current directory).